# Swift PM Package.resolved

Tags: swift5, package-managers

Since a package dependency is typically setup for a range of versions (i.e. Github tags) it would be good to be able to “see” the actual version incorporated into an app. There is not, to my knowledge, any easy way for an app to programmatically query the version number (Github tag) of the version that has been downloaded and compiled into your app.

I have found the Package.resolved file (buried deeply in the *xcproj file) and developed code to parse it to obtain version information.

Is there a simpler way to obtain this information?

Comment: `The Swift Package Manager is a tool for managing the distribution of Swift code. It’s integrated with the Swift build system to automate the process of downloading, compiling, and linking dependencies.` [source](https://swift.org/package-manager/). Getting anything at runtime is quite far out of SPM's scope.